# How to add a property to a Rails 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Book model with two attributes, Title and Subtitle. When subtitle is blank, I want just the title returned, otherwise it should return the both. Is the best, most succinct way to do so, by adding the following to the model?

```
def full_title
  self.subtitle.blank? ? self.title : "#{self.title}: #{self.subtitle}"
end
```

It does work, but something seems a bit off, perhaps the abundance of selfs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll work with or without the `self`

```
def full_title
  subtitle.blank? ? title : "#{title}: #{subtitle}"
end
```

Here's another way to do it but I think yours is more *railsy*

```
def full_title
  subtitle.blank? ? title : title + ": " + subtitle
end
```

Answer (score 5):

you could also make it even a little more succinct and remove the logic:

```
def full_title
  [title, subtitle].compact.join(": ")
end
```

Comment: nice, i'm upvoting your answer

Comment: I think this answer is pretty neat, but the intention is a little less clear so am going with the other answer. Thanks for your input.